# Grails Bootstrap addTo an extended abstract class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, grails-orm

I'm new in Grails and i'm trying to create something like this:

I have an abstract class called Media, and two classes that extends from Media: CD and DVD. I have a class User that can have 0 or more Medias (Cds or Dvds):

Media.groovy

```
    abstract class Media {

    String title
    String year         

    static belongsTo = [user: User]

    static constraints = {
        title blank: false
        year nullable: true         
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

User.groovy

```
class User{

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static hasMany = [medias: Media]
    ...
```

Cd.groovy

```
class Cd extends Media {

    String artist

    static constraints = {
        artist blank: false
    }

    String toString() { return title}
}
```

In Bootstrap I do this:

Bootstrap.groovy

```
def userRole = Role.findOrSaveWhere(authority: 'ROLE_USER')
def user= User.findOrSaveWhere(username: 'user', password: '1234')

if(!user.authorities.contains(userRole)) {
    UserRole.create(user, userRole, true)
}

def cd1 = new Cd(title: "Universal", year: "2010", artist: "Borknagar", user: user).save(failOnError: true)
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
>   - Field error in object 'org.grails.Cd' on field 'user': rejected value [null];

If I remove the "user" field from cd1, it works but the "cd1" will not belong to the "user". How can I add "cd1" to "user"? I cant create a new Media because its an abstract call.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Belongs to adds a back reference. Did you try http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html

So user.addToMedias(cd1);